# jOOQ cannot map PostgreSQL columns to make JPA happy

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jooq

In a Spring Boot application (v. 1.3.2), I'm trying to generate using jOOQ all the POJOs that are mapping the database tables such that they get also annotated to be used with JPA. The db is PostgreSQL.

The issue is that jOOQ maps some types, like `jsonb`, as an `Object`. Seems that Hibernate doesn't like this. I get an exception like:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: model.tables.pojos.Product type: object
```

Funny thing, if I replace in the generated file the `Object` with a `String`, then everything works fine. Clearly this cannot be a solution, otherwise I don't see why I should use a tool to auto-generate my annotated entities.

Any idea how to solve this? Is it possible that jOOQ cannot map in a more serious way these values (e.g., `json`, `jsonb`, `ean13`, etc.). Even a `String` would be better, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Supporting vendor-specific data types with jOOQ

The standard way to add support for binding vendor-specific data types with jOOQ is by providing converters or data type bindings:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

The data type binding page even contains an example of how to do this with PostgreSQL's JSON data type.

#### Working with jOOQ and JPA

jOOQ doesn't fully implement JPA. If you want to use the JPA-annotated POJOs as true entities, you're probably better off generating them through Hibernate (which also annotates `@OneToMany` and other useful properties, unlike jOOQ).

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify a converter for jOOQ:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/